# How to find the host of a website using PHP?

Tags: php, hosting, whois

I am developing a website which will find the host of the website, i am using the **tracert** method and then using the end result of the output as the host, which ends with ip addresses sometimes instead of the domain names.

Anybody has any ideas on this?

My current work can be seen at:
http://ganguro.highviews.co.cc/

Please advice.

Thank you!

Comment: a single IP can have hundreds of host names. Which one do you need?

Comment: @sarwar-erfan sorry i don't follow what you mean?

Comment: He is saying that one IP can be a shared host with multiple domains (i.e. godaddy will use ip 1.2.3.4 as a shared server with me.com, you.com, them.com, etc). While some servers are shared most domains will have a specific IP.  UNIX has a nice utility called dig (ex: dig -x <ip address>) that will provide the host name for an IP, perhaps you can write a script that will return that value? In the case of a shared host that is opened based on headers, you may have a tougher time there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/knowledge/database.html) api to get find who is hosting a website.

also refer to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303726/find-who-is-hosting-a-website-using-php/5303752#5303752)